# How to fix "Provider must implement the class 'System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateStoreProviderBase' error asp.net

Tags: asp.net, redis, azure-caching

I am trying to implement Azure cache for redis to manage session's in my application. This is working on localhost. After hosting to IIS got compile error in webconfig file.

I have created azure cache for redis in azure portal. I have made respective changes in code. It's working when I run with source code on local host. After hosting to IIS got the following error

> "Provider must implement the class
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateStoreProviderBase

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="myhostname" accessKey="Key1" ssl="true" />
      </providers>    
    </sessionState>
```

Module added as following

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleAsync, Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

I expected sessions values to store on azure cache for redis. But It's not working after hosting on IIS.

Comment: are you transforming your web.config when deploying to IIS?

Comment: @DdW - I'm having the same issue - have the config as above and am transforming the web.config via octopus deploy when deploying to an Azure App Service

Comment: @anD666 Be careful with transforming, especially the modules section is tricky. Look at the transformed endresult, and compare with the local version.

Comment: @DdW - The transformation isn't touching the modules section. it's just adding the session state section.

Comment: @anD666 you need the modules section as well...

Comment: @DdW - sorry, poor explanation in my previous comment. The module for the SessionStateModuleAsync is already in the web.config. When I pull down the files from the web server they are as expected. The extracted web directory even works locally so I'm at a loss

Comment: Any news on this? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 9):

You can try this under app.config/web.config

```
<modules>
<remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleAsync,Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

if this doesn't work as well, if you have an option, use non-SSL port and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone passing by that might have the same issue and for whom adding the Session tag didn't work, your application pool might be configured as 'Classic'

From [this post](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/issues/123), it seems **Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleAsync** doesn't support classic application pools

You need to switch it to 'Integrated' like so :

[image]

[Microsoft official application pools documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/)